# Use AJAX offline

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms, asp.net-ajax

I deployed an app to a local server without access to the internet and I have all my resources local and referenced. However, when it's running, it auto-generates the following code

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.6/1/webForms.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.5.1/1/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.5.1/1/MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have said files locally but I don't know how to use them instead of the links.

Comment: Download those 3 js files and make the source a local path.

Comment: @VDWWD as mentioned, i have all the files on the server and referenced

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy the files locally:

Download the script files (webForms.js, MicrosoftAjax.js, MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js) from the ASP.NET CDN
Place them in a suitable folder within your application's directory structure, such as a "Scripts" or "Resources" folder.

2. Update the script references:
   In your ASPX pages:
   Replace the CDN links with paths pointing to the local files. For example:
   HTML

Ensure the paths are correct relative to the location of your ASPX pages.

3. Check for script manager configuration:
   If you're using a ScriptManager control in your pages, make sure its EnableCdn property is set to false to prevent automatic CDN references:

<asp:ScriptManager EnableCdn="false" runat="server">